# nginx FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"

Tags: nginx, centos, php, php-fpm

Been troubleshooting this for hours now. I've gone through every iteration of the question here on serverfault and tried everything. Nothing seems to be working.

Basically all non-PHP works but any PHP script triggers `*1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream`

I'm running NGINX + PHP(7)-FPM on CentOS 7.

php-fpm pool conf:

```
[www]

user = web
group = www-data

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

listen.owner = web
listen.group = www-data
;listen.mode = 0660

listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35

slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log

php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/wsdlcache
```

relevant location block in nginx/www.conf:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root /var/www/public;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

fastcgi_param include:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: What's in the fastcgi_params include?

Comment: @jedifans updated post

Comment: Exact same error, even images load... Was any solution ever found @Rob

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a [fastcgi_split_path_info](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_split_path_info) declaration in your location block, above the SCRiPT_FILENAME declaration:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
```